# var in a sql request

Tags: php, sql

I have a problem with a sql request. I try to update my database with some var. So my request is in a function with two `char` in parameters. Then, I write them into my request like that :

```
$sql = "UPDATE public.traitement SET ".$champsDB." WHERE id_traitement='".$id_traitement."'";
```

When I try to echo it, I've got nothing in `$champsDB` :

**UPDATE public.traitement SET WHERE id_traitement='COL_CFB2'**

but if I echo it all alone, I have what I expect :

**id_traitement='COL_CFB2',traitement='Apport de Compost de Fumier de Bovin (150 - 200 kg N/ha). sans fertilisation
 minérale',code_traitement='CFB2',id_essai='COL'**

I really don't understand why I can echo it and why I can't get it in my request.

**EDIT**

Here is my entire code :

```
function update_traitement($champsDB,$id_traitement)
    {
            echo $champsDB; //This echo works with my correct data
            $conn_string = "host=localhost port=5432 dbname=test_postgre user=postgres password='1234'";
            $dbconn = pg_connect($conn_string);

            $sql = "UPDATE public.traitement SET $champsDB WHERE id_traitement='".$id_traitement."'";
            //$res = pg_query($sql) or die("Pb avec la requete: $sql");

            echo $sql; //This echo doesn't work, I don't get my "$champDB"

    }
```

**EDIT 2**:

Here is my tab with my values :
[image]

After submitting, I make a char with all this var that I called `$champsDB`. And I put this var into my function `update_traitement`.
Help !

Comment: I can't see anything wrong with the line of code you've quoted here, so I suspect a typo. If you can post more of your code, we've got a better chance of helping you. On a side note, you don't need to use ". all the time - you can simply use $sql = "blah blah $param blah blah"; and $param will be expanded in the same way as "blah ".$param."blah", which can make the code a little easier to read.

Comment: don't know what your question is :( ... *$champsDB* is only seen in your update statement and it seems to be null or empty or not set .... so check it before

Comment: @Eddy I edited my post with all my code

Comment: @donald123 I checked it before with an echo and it works, that's why I don't understand why it doesn't work in my request

Comment: update table set `field1 = value` where field2=something , you are setting `$champsDB` to which field or $champsDB is a field then where is the value?

Comment: @Bender My `$champsDB` contains a char with the field and the value. I put the entire value of `$champsDB` in my post.

Comment: @Lison and you are putting that value in which field in table? your query missing where to put `$champsDB` value part.

Comment: `UPDATE table_name`
`SET column1=value, column2=value2,...`
`WHERE some_column=some_value ` you are missing `column1`

Comment: @Bender "_id_traitement='COL_CFB2',traitement='Apport de Compost de Fumier de Bovin (150 - 200 kg N/ha). sans fertilisation minérale',code_traitement='CFB2',id_essai='COL'_" This is what is in my $champsDB. So, for example, column1 is "id_traitement", value1 is "COL_CFB2" ...

Comment: can you post screen shot or table schema , it is easier for me to explain in that way

Comment: @Lison try this ' $sql = "UPDATE public.traitement SET". $champsDB ."WHERE id_traitement='".$id_traitement."'";'

Comment: @Bender The quotes don't change anything :/ I will edit my post with some screen shot

Comment: @Lison which version of php are you working with?

Comment: @Paolo version 5.6.8

Comment: What's the content of `$champsDB` if you echo it again directly before echoing `$sql`? Where do you echo this to, as HTML output into a browser? When you inspect the HTML source code in the browser, is there still nothing between `SET WHERE` (small chance there may be some brackets added somewhere that aren't rendered correctly in the browser)?